# jQuery iterate over object with $.each

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, iteration, each

I have an object `options`: `options = {title : 'title1', name : 'name1', url : 'url1', etc.}`

which is passed in as a parameter to a function.  I'm trying to iterate over that object, pass it through another function `evaluate`, and store the result in another object `opts`, like so:

```
var opts = new Object();

$.each(options, function(key,value){
opts.key = evaluate(element, value);
});
```

The `evaluate(element,value)` works fine, but the problem is that `opts` ends up looking like:

```
{key : eval(element,url1)}
```

instead of

```
{title : eval(element,title1), name : eval(element,name1), etc.}
```

That is, `key` gets passed literally instead of being evaluated, and gets overwritten with each iteration with the last property in `options`.

Do I have the right syntax in my assignment line?  I also tried:

```
opts = {key : eval(element,val)}
```

which gave the same result as above.  I can also convert the object to an array within the `$.each` iteration.  I've tried several ways of doing that, also unsuccessfully.  If someone can show me that route, that would be great too.

(This is for a jQuery plugin, and I'm testing using Firebug in Firefox).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over Object Literal Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354834/iterate-over-object-literal-values)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've discovered this is the literal key 'key':

```
opts.key = evaluate(element, value);
```

To use a dynamic key use `[]`:

```
opts[key] = evaluate(element, value);
```

Specific example:

```
var o = {};
o["test"] = "foo";
alert(o.test);
```